# Algorithm for calculating the combination of sums of 3 numbers squared

Tags: c++, algorithm

It's my first post to stack overflow and I would like some help I'm trying to program an algorithm for my c++ class and not being too familiar with english math terms, I find it hard to search for stuff like this online. I need to calculate all the different possible combinations of the sum of 3 squared numbers, which theres <= than a set number for instance

```
`x^2+y^2+z^2 <= n^2`
```

For example

- if n=1, then the possible combinations are

  ```
  (x=0  y=0  z=1),
  (x=0  y=1  z=0),
  (x=1  y=0  z=0)
  ```
- if n=2 then the possible combinations are all the previous plus

  ```
  (x=0 y=1 z=1)
  (x=1 y=1 z=0)
  (x=1 y=0 z=1)
  (x=2 y=0 z=0)
  (x=0 y=2 z=0)
  (x=0 y=0 z=2)
  ```

I do have to do the same thing for n=100 and find it hard to make 3 loops that produce this sequence and cover every combination, as well as counter to count them and print them on screen.

My code is this:

```
int i,j,k,pl=0;
for (i=0; i<=100; i++) // last digit
{
    if (i==k)
        k=k-1;
    if (i*i+j*j+k*k<=100*100)
    {
        pl++;
        cout<<k<<"  "<<j<<" "<<i;
    }
    for(j=0; j<=i; j++) //second digit
    {
        if (j==i)
            i=i-1;
        if (i*i+j*j+k*k<=100*100)
        {
            pl++;
            cout<<k<<"  "<<j<<" "<<i;
        }
        for(k=0; k<=j; k++) //first digit
        {
            if (k==j)
                j=j-1;
            if (i*i+j*j+k*k<=100*100)
            {
                pl++;
                cout<<k<<"  "<<j<<" "<<i;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For now, its stuck on an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

To enumerate all distinct combinations of *i*, *j* and *k* with *i*, *j*, and *k* between 0 and 100 inclusive:

```
for (i = 0; i <= 100; ++i)
for (j = i; j <= 100; ++j)
for (k = j; k <= 100; ++k)
  {
     // Do something with i, j, and k
  }
```

**Note**: This gives all **distinct** combinations. For example, after it has enumerated the combination *i* = 0, *j* = 1, *k* = 2 it will not produce *i* = 2, *j* = 0, *k* = 1 because 0 1 2 and 2 0 1 are not distinct combinations.

If you want all combinations, without eliminating duplicates, then three ordinary loops will obviously suffice:

```
for (i = 0; i <= 100; ++i)
for (j = 0; j <= 100; ++j)
for (k = 0; k <= 100; ++k)
  {
     // Do something with i, j, and k
  }
```

Comment: Can `i` be 1 and `j` = 0 ?

Comment: @EdHeal: Sure it can; but that case was already enumerated as `i` = 0 and `j` = 1. For example, with 3 instead of 100: 000, 001, 002, 003, 011, 012, 013, 022, 023, 033, 111, 112, 113, 122, 123, 222, 223, 333. Try to find a missing combination.

Comment: thank you for you comment i tried your suggestion but its again stuck on an infinite loop

Comment: @KilleXGR: This loop is assuredly not infinite, it will obviously loop less than 101^3 times. And please _do not_ modify _i_, _j_ or _k_ in the loop body.

Comment: your right but how then i can make a loop that goes like this 0 0 1,0 1 0,1 0 0, 0 1 1 i have to modify the loops to get zeroed again

Comment: @KilleXGR: Edited the answer; however, in such problems it is generally assumed that you want only distinct combinations.